# Most recent added record into database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How should i get most recent added record from database, where COL_2 should == param that I pass into it.
I can get all records where COL_2 is equal to param with this code, but I need only recent one

```
    public Cursor getRowsLast(String param) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] COLS = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_1,DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3,DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
    String where = param;
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, COLS, DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + " = '" + where + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to get the most recent row in a table is to have a column defined in the table for the time of insert/update. Make sure this value is accurate at the time of insert/update, and create an index on it. You can then sort (descending) on this column to determine which one is the most recent - it will be the first row.

Answer (score 0):

As the automatically generated ID values increase with every insert, the row with the highest ID will be the one that was inserted most recently. So add an 'order by _id desc' and the first row will be the most recently inserted one.

Note - this does not cover updates. If you need the row most recently inserted or updated, you'll have to use an additional timestamp column like Doug Stevenson suggested.

Comment: I probably said it badly. I only need row where ID is highest number from all rows where Column 2 == param.

Comment: The solution is still the same. Your where-conditions filters the rows before the 'order by' is applied. My suggestion will still give you the most recently inserted row that matches your where-condition.